# ICS Append Event

Tags: python, file, calendar, icalendar

I have a function in range, and I would like to append events to the ICS file, but I can't find the function...
any ideas?

```
            def ics():
            
                event = Event()
                cal = Calendar()
                cal.add('prodid', 'IVU-Monatseinteilung Tool')
                cal.add('version', '2.0')
                event.add('summary', string1)
                event.add('description', f'Kommentar: {soup_kommentar}, Schiff: {b}, Funktion: {soup_funktion}, Schichtdauer: {soup_schichtdauer}, Bezahlte Zeit: {soup_bezahltezeit}, Mannschaft: {crew_list2}\n')
                event.add('dtstart', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd,dienstBH,dienstBM,0,tzinfo=UTC))
                event.add('dtend', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd,dienstEH,dienstEM,0,tzinfo=UTC))
                event.add('dtstamp', datetime(2005,4,4,0,10,0,tzinfo=UTC))
                event['uid'] = '20050115T101010/27346262376@mxm.dk'
                event.add('priority', 5)

                cal.add_component(event)

                f = open(f'{myPath}/{userfinder}-{month}-{year}.ics', 'wb')
                f.write(cal.to_ical())


                print(f'Datum: {soup_datum} Dienst: {string1}{tagesinfo2} --> Mannschaft: {crew_list2} --> OK')
            ics()
```

Answer (score 0):

To append more than one events to the calendar it is pretty straightforward

Basically, just tweak a little bit on the coding logic in your question.
As you will need to add the events to the calendar before you create the ics file

For example:

```
cal = Calendar()
cal.add('prodid', 'IVU-Monatseinteilung Tool')
cal.add('version', '2.0')
event_one = Event()
event_one.add('summary', 'Meeting')
event_one.add('dtstart', datetime(2023, 1, 27,dienstBH,dienstBM,0,tzinfo=UTC))

# Necessary properties for event_one

event_two = Event()
event_two.add('summary', 'Bistro Cafe Chilling Session')
event_two.add('dtstart', datetime(2023, 1, 31,dienstBH,dienstBM,0,tzinfo=UTC))

# Append events to calendar
cal.add_component(event_one)
cal.add_component(event_two)

f = open(f'{myPath}/{userfinder}-{month}-{year}.ics', 'wb')
f.write(cal.to_ical())
f.close()
```